# Flutter: How to use the api key stored in .env file in vercel deployment without committing it to github?

Tags: flutter, github, vercel, openai-api

I am trying to deploy my flutter web app on vercel, but it is getting failed with this error: `Error detected in pubspec.yaml: No file or variants found for asset: assets/.env.`

I've my `.env` stored under `assets` folder which I have mentioned the `pubspec.yaml` file. The problem is that this .env file is also mentioned in the `.gitignore` file which is stopping it from committing to github, which in turn is causing the deployment error on vercel.

I tried following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186007/how-do-i-use-my-api-keys-in-vercel-deployment-but-hide-it-from-github) like this:

```
Future<String> generateText(prompt) async {
      // var apiKey = dotenv.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'];
      var apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
      final url = Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions');
      final headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey'
      };
      final body = jsonEncode(
          {'messages': prompt, 'temperature': 0.2, 'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo'});
      final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        final text = data['choices'][0]['message']['content'].toString();
        return text;
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Something went wrong. Try again.')));
        throw Exception('Failed to generate text');
    }
  }
```

but then I am getting the error `Undefined name 'process'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.`

How can I use the API Key in my vercel deployment without exposing it on Github?